# getElementsByClassName[i] returns undefinend

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, addeventlistener, nodelist

I have a few elements with the class "preview". I want to make one of them clickable, so first I wanted to find out it's index number in the HTML collection by

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("preview"));
```

and this did return a HTML collection where I could see the index number of the wanted element is 3.

Now I want to assign an event listener to it, but it returns "Cannot assign 'addEventListener' to undefined"

```
document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[3].addEventListener("click","someFunction()")
```

Comment: are you using 0 base indexing?

Comment: You don't need to use "" to call a function. So it should be 
document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[3].addEventListener("click",someFunction())

Comment: If there are 3 elements, it should be `.getElementsByClassName("preview")[2]` instead of `.getElementsByClassName("preview")[3]`.

Comment: Shouldn't that number be 2 instead?

Comment: Continuing to the comment of @AnamulHasan , you don't need to give parenthesis while declaring event handler. It should be 
 `document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[3].addEventListen‌​er("click",someFunct‌​ion)`

Comment: i know that. I was just trying to tell him about the quotation. Anyway, thanks for pointing out @PawanKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are just `3` elements with class `preview`, then the last index of this collection is `2` and not  `3` as `NodeList` collection is `0` indexed like any other `array`.

Change this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[3].addEventListener("click","someFunction()")
```

To the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[2].addEventListener("click",someFunction)
```

**Note:**

- Note that I removed the `" "` wrapping the callback function of the
  `addEventListener`, and removed the two parenthesis too, so the
  function won't be called when you attach the event listener.
- Make sure your code is invoked after the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Did the exact same thing, console:
script.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at script.js:7

Comment: @SHCMostWanted Can you please show us all your relevant code? Maybe you are calling the code before the page is loaded.

Comment: that is exactly what the problem was, thank you... solved